# how to change from Apple Developer Organisation Program to Apple Developer Enterprise Program?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program, enterprise-distribution

i am new to iOS so by mistake i enrolled for Apple Developer Organisation Program (99 USD per membership year), my requirement is to distribute apps to only for selective number of customers but not through Appstore. So by some RnD i got to know about Apple Developer Enterprise Program (299 USD per membership year) which i found relevant. My Apple Developer Organisation Program is still unused and fresh i.e no app is pushed yet on Appstore. So can i change the Program ? If yes then what is the procedure ? please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to contact apple. I also believe that is only available for companies (that might not be correct). [This page](https://developer.apple.com/support/account/) will tell you how to change to a company account.

Comment: i have created account for my company itself.